# Finding Sum of Squares

Tags: python

In Python: We will provide you with a value N. You should calculate the sum of each value of N squared from 0 up to and including N.

In mathematical notation, this is written as  ∑Ni=0i2

So if we passed in 3, you would output  02+12+22+32=14  The 2's are exponents

Comment: Please clarify your question, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put your homework here.

```py
sum(i ** 2 for i in range(n))
```